# Give function get file extension for you

Tags: php, file

I have written a function that retrieves the extension from a given file name for you. I would like to make this more efficient and increase it's performance.

```
<?php
function getExt($filename) {
    //if(!is_file($filename)) return '';
    $n = strlen($filename);
    if($n<2) return '';
    $non_ext = '';
    $ext = '';
    for($i=$n;$i--;$i>=1) {
        $c = $filename[$i];
        if($c==='.') {
            $ext = '.'.$non_ext.$ext;
            $non_ext = '';
        }else
            $non_ext = $c.$non_ext;
    }
    return $ext;
}
$filename = "asdfasdfasd.tar.gz";
$ext = getExt($filename);
var_dump($ext);
?>
```

Comment: You need only one line of code while Php PATHINFO_EXT already did the function: `$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: `$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` Dont try reinventing the wheel. Instead **Read The Manual**

Comment: _Small but possibly relevant note_ Your function does not provide the extension, it provides everything after the first DOT in the filename. People use dots in filenames all the time.

Comment: This line gives the exact same output as your function, meaning "after first dot".  `Var_dump(explode(".", $filename, 2)[1]);` https://3v4l.org/3rj1g

Comment: @Andreas Ahhh  you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP inbuilt function. Inbuilt functions are the fastest.

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: I think this has been quite adequately covered in comments

Comment: You cannot get more than one dot sign in extension from file by this PHP built-in function, but you can get that with my function. But my function is mistake some thing, I have to comment out this line //if(!is_file($filename)) return '';

Answer (score 0):

I like this method suggess by @Andreas

```
$filename = "asdfasdfasdgz";
var_dump(@explode(".", $filename, 2)[1]);
```